# Short message encryption with only javascript to generate it in a URL

Tags: javascript, security, encryption

I'd like to present an idea to you that I think might help the privacy of the average user. I would appreciate any comment or suggestion on this.

I've been struggling for quite some time now with the need for a simple tool that I could share and use with my contacts who are only average users and not familiar at all with any cryptographic technology or the current tools available.

I'm planning to create a solution where one can easily encrypt a text message or a file with a single password and send it in email or chat or through whatever channel to somebody else. The solution should be entirely platform independent and usable without the need to install any extra softwares.

There are some text encryption websites out there that run client side encryption from JavaScript entirely. I find this approach currently the only possible solution. Also, there are libs for JS that already implement encryption:

http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/
http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Though the mentioned approaches store the message on their server, requiring you and your contact to trust it entirely. Because the server might present a different JS code to the user when visiting it after he gets the message by steeling the password and so revealing the secret.

While many think that it's not a good idea to do anything regarding cryptographic tasks in JS, I believe there is a need for a tool that is really platform independent (can be used on any tablet or PC) and still incredibly easy to use. The idea behind this is that I believe something is better than nothing. Sending information in plain text in email for decades with our current technology is wrong in most cases. There are times when we do need to share sensitive info via email and the other side might have any kind of system.

I intend to avoid the use of public key cryptography for the following reasons:
- it is very complicated to setup including the signing of each others' keys
- complicated to use it
- the user can loose his keys
- most of the time it needs and external software to be used and installed too
- a single password can be easily shared personally one time with my contact and he or she can keep it written on a paper wherever

The solution I came up with could be the following:

First of all, the browser and the operating system under it should be considered trusted.

There would be a static index.html page with embedded JavaScript. The page shows a textarea for the message and a textbox for the password. When hitting enter, the JS code generates a URL that itself will contain the encrypted message in base64 encoding. After digging I figured that 2000 bytes can be used for URLs just fine in every cases, so 1600 or 800 characters could be enough for short messages. This still needs planning.

So the encrypted message would travel with the URL. The website serving the index.html would of course use SSL with a valid certificate. While it seems an easy taks, of course it is not. The JS implementation should be carefully created to avoid easy attacks on it.

(URL shortener services could be used for it too).

Also, the question stands: How can I make sure that my contact can be certain about the origin of my message?

Well, the other side has to check if the domain is correct. Beside this, the implementation must avoid the rest of the attacks. If the URL gets changed during the travel of the email, then maximum the other side won't be able to decode the message with the password. That's what I believe. That it can be implemented this way.

About the file sharing. The solution should have a possibility to browse for a file, then encrypt it, then put it out for download to the user. This is just for him to be able to create the encrypted form of the file without the need for external tools. Then he could upload it to the cloud of his choice wherever (Google drive, Skydrive etc) and use that link in the URL of the JS solution to send it to his contact.

So if another link travels with the link, then the file from the remote host gets downloaded, decrypted and sent for download. All in his browser. If it's an encrypted message in base64 form, then it gets printed on the page after decryption (by the user providing his password of course).

Pros compared to other solutions:
- no need to implement a storage because no message nor file will be stored on the server, so the big players' services could be used
- therefore no need to reimplement the wheel regarding the storage question
- no need to trust a 3rd party because the server could easily be ours because it would be extremely easy to set up and serve it
- easy with even a free provider to host the static index.html
- because of its simplicity, the server can be hardened much better
- easy to encrypt with it in practice
- if one needs it, he could use the index.html by clicking on it from his desktop too, but that's not part of the original idea

My questions to you all are:

Do you find any flaw in my theory above? Could this really serve the average people by providing a usable tool for them that is more than nothing in times when they do need to send sensitive info to others?

Or does anything like that exist yet? Are there any better approaches? Different technology maybe?

Thank You.

Comment: How do I send the password to the recipient?

Comment: Some of what you're talking about is similar to how mega.co.nz operates, but you've got quite a few flaws in what you're proposing, because *cyptography is hard* - like, really really PHD level hard, to get right.

Comment: Btw, try posting this to http://security.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Also: interesting you say that you don't want to use public key encryption. Why not look at ways to make the signing process easy. That way you're adding to, and building on, an existing solid foundation instead of trying to solve the same problems again.

Comment: I give the password to my contact personally one time. That'll do I believe. You have the same problem with public key too. You can tell the fingerprint on the phone, but the same with the password.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't have anything to do with cryptography. I would use the already implemented libs. The goal is as I wrote above: everybody should be able to use it without any deeper knowledge and on any platform without any extra tools but their browser.

Comment: The program is half ready and can can be tested partly. The encryption of text messages work. Many things still missing and not final at all. Here is a demo: https://rawgithub.com/cba74/crypt74/master/index.html

Comment: File en / decryption works now with firefox browser.

Comment: Everything works on Firefox, Chrome and Opera browsers. Testing is more than welcome!